# Does Actian PSQL 13.31 (Zen) have the equivalent of SQL Server "IN" in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-in, zen, actian

I have read a ton of Actian PSQL docs but cannot find out how to duplicate this simple SQL verb:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1, value2, ...);
```

Does Actian PSQL 13.31 have the equivalent of SQL Server `IN` in the `WHERE` clause?

They do have an `IN` verb but it does something totally different.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine.  The formatting of the statement has no impact.

select * from "Class" WHERE ID IN (160, 161 )

If you run that SQL in PCC in the DemoData db I get only two records. Not sure what I was doing wrong but you guys got me going. Thank you.

Comment: For later reference, the docs (currently for version 16) for the SELECT statement are here: https://docs.actian.com/zen/v15/index.html#page/sqlref/sqlref.SELECT.htm , and the docs for the version you have installed should be available local on your hard-drive (Press F1 in PCC)